# Exercise question about Thévenin theorem

Tags: thevenin

I'm new to Thevenin's theorem and I'm trying to figure out this simple one.
[image]

I did what's on the next figure. I'm wondering If I can join the cables as I did and I could say that the voltage across \$R_{1}\$ is also \$V_{th}\$ since they are in parallel.  The answer says \$R_{eq}=R_{1}\$. But I'm getting \$R_{eq}=R_{1}+R_2\$.

[image]

Thank you for your time!

Comment: are you trying to compute A?

Comment: Yes A with respect to the ground node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Req = R2. See connection below.

R1 is shorted (V1 = 0) and R3 is open (I3 = 0)

[image]

Comment: Ohhh. Now I get. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

R1 ia shorted with the conducting wire in place of V1 so the parallel equivalent resistance is 0 ohm (For two resistances in parallel, equivalent resistance is $R=\ frac{R1×R2}{R1+R2}$, If any resistance is zero, equivalent resisatnce is also zero). R3 has been open circuited correctly therefore the thevenin resistance is R2 and not R1

Comment: I don't understand the part "\$R_{1}\$  is shorted with the wire in place of \$V_1\$". Doesn't it become a closed circuit?

Comment: For two resistances in parallel, equivalent resistance is \frac{R1×R2}{R1+R2}, If any resistance is zero, equivalent resisatnce is also zero